# "runOnUIThread" incrementally running everytime I go back to the activity

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a timer which runs on the activity's OnCreate method as shown below. When run, the timer increments as it should. Showing:

> 00:00,
>   00:01,
>   00:02,
>   etc.

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
        final TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                        String timer = sdf.format(new Date(counter * 1000L));
                        timerText.setText(timer);
                        counter++;

                    }
                });
            }};
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
```

However, when I revisit the activity, the timer's interval increases. If I revisit it the first time, the interval becomes 2 i.e.

> 00:00,
>   00:02,
>   00:04,
>   etc.

Revisiting it again makes the interval 3 i.e.

> 00:00,
>   00:03,
>   00:06,
>   etc.

And the intervals keep incrementing.
I deduced the runOnUIThread method is being run **n** times, where **n** is the number of times onCreate has been accessed, but I don't really know what to do about it.

Comment: Dispose your timer in OnDestroy method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Timer constructor that specifies it to be a daemon `new Timer(true)` so that if it exits the timer thread exits too.
Also consider [cancelling](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29) the timer before exiting on [onDestroy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) or [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) for example.